Extrude/ scale faces along the edges (keeping the same angle)
I am trying to extrude some faces of a cube with same angle as the edges are on, I cannot find a simple way to do it.
Desired outcome is in the last image.
With the default cube, I scaled the top face 1.5 times.

4 Loop Cuts Vertically.

Want to extrude top 4 faces up with same angle following the edge.

I tried edge sliding the four faces which gives the expected result for the four faces but for the other one it stretches the edge with them.


Want to have the same extrusion but with the same angle (they are not on the same angle; I manually extrude them up and roughly scaled them).
Thank you for reading this, have an awesome blending.

My solution is a workaround:
Duplicate the mesh, go to edit mode, delete top faces, select the top edge ring, press G,G,C, move the mouse and confirm.
Then recreate the top faces and use the duplicate to snap an edge loop to the previous location.



Thank you for answering my question, I did not get the part after I recreate the faces on top and then how can I use the duplicate to snap an edge loop to the previous location?
I can make a loop cut and snap it to the previous point which will the expected output as shown in your second image
Also, I only want the four faces to be extruded.
For that after sliding the top edge ring, I have to delete the face and edges which I don't want and then I have to fill the rest to get the output.
Please correct me if I am getting your response wrong.

I added the snapping suggestion only because when sliding I loose the exact location of the previous edge loop, but feel free to interpret the answer as needed to your own modeling task. Please mark the answer as accepted if it was useful, thank you.

To snap an edge loop set the snapping as "Edge", select the edge loop (Alt click), press GG to slide the loop and click on an appropriate (top) edge of the object copy.

The idea is to duplicate the whole mesh in object mode, to use only as reference for snapping. Then in Edit mode you can slide the top edges, then add a new edge loop (Ctrl R), then slide it until it snaps on the reference object.

I understand how you are using the reference object for snapping, after snapping I have the top faces extruded and the old mesh also.
After that to get the desired outcome, I have to delete the face and edges which I don't want and then have to connect the vertex and then fill the open faces.
